# I have 2 Audio devices installed(MorphVOX, and Voxal) that I would like to remove

Tags: audio, filesystem, settings

I have already deleted the applications for the audio devices(MorphVOX and Voxal) when trying to remove them from the Audio Midi application the "-" is greyed out. Additionally there seems to be no sign of the files in my audio folders and I am unable to find a extensions folder

Comment: Do you are tried `sudo rm -rf /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SBVirtualMic.driver` ?

Answer (score 1):

Golden rule for application installs - if it needed a full installer it also needs a full uninstaller.

Customer support for individual products usually have an uninstaller for if you didn't already follow their instructions. I found MorphVOX for you - https://screamingbee.com/Docs/MorphVOXMac/Faq#QUninstallDriver

For the future, you should get [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (Freeware) & use it to uninstall apps. It will tidy up most extras that even regular apps leave behind.

Just to note, uninstallers are sometimes installed alongside the app itself; sometimes in the same folder as the app iteself, sometimes in Utilities, or sometimes on the installer .dmg. Always worth checking those places out.